# How to make chart axis number formats match the data set number formats

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently running VBA code that automatically formats charts for me. The section of the code that sets the number format of the y-axis labels is as follows:

```
If chart1.Type <> xlPie And chart1.Type <> xlDoughnut Then

    If InStr(chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat, "%") <> 0 And _
    chart1.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale < 0.1 Then
        chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#0.0%;(#0.0)%"
    ElseIf InStr(chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat, "%") <> 0 And _
    chart1.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale >= 0.1 Then
        chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "##0%;(##0)%"
    ElseIf InStr(chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat, ".") <> 0 And _
    InStr(chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat, "%") = 0 And _
        Len(chart1.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale) > 2 Then _
        chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#0.0;(#0.0)"
    Else
        chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0;(#,##0)"
    End If

    If InStr(chart1.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat, "yy") <> 0 Then _
    chart1.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "mmm yy"
```

I've tried amending this code so that is can also handle the number format: "#,##0.0x;(#,##0.0)x;0.0x"

This is my amended code:

```
If chart1.Type <> xlPie And chart1.Type <> xlDoughnut Then

    If InStr(chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat, "%") <> 0 And _
    chart1.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale < 0.1 Then
        chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#0.0%;(#0.0)%"
    ElseIf InStr(chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat, "%") <> 0 And _
    chart1.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale >= 0.1 Then
        chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "##0%;(##0)%"
    ElseIf InStr(chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat, ".") <> 0 And _
    InStr(chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat, "%") = 0 And _
        Len(chart1.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale) > 2 Then _
        chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#0.0;(#0.0)"
    ElseIf InStr(chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat, "x") <> 0 And _
    chart1.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale < 0.1 Then
        chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#0.0x;(#0.0)x"
    ElseIf InStr(chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat, "x") <> 0 And _
    chart1.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale >= 0.1 Then
        chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "##0x;(##0)x"
    ElseIf InStr(chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat, ".") <> 0 And _
    InStr(chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat, "x") = 0 And _
        Len(chart1.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale) > 2 Then _
        chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#0.0;(#0.0)"
    Else
        chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0;(#,##0)"
    End If

    If InStr(chart1.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat, "yy") <> 0 Then _
    chart1.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "mmm yy"
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.

Basically if I have the data set:

2016    0.3x

2017    0.4x

2018    0.5x

The chart's y-axis labels don't have x's

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Thomas

Comment: Can you elaborate on: **this doesn't seem to work**? Does it not do what you need it to do? or it's throwing an error?

Comment: Hi Zac, it doesn't do what it needs to (currently no errors). Basically if I have the data set:

2016  0.3x
2017  0.4x
2018  0.5x

The chart's y-axis labels don't have x's

Answer (score 0):

The `Else If` statements

```
ElseIf InStr(chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat, "x") <> 0 And _
chart1.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale < 0.1 Then
    chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#0.0x;(#0.0)x"
ElseIf InStr(chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat, "x") <> 0 And _
chart1.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale >= 0.1 Then
    chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "##0x;(##0)x"
```

Are only evaluating true when `chart1.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat` already has an `x` in it, which means that unless your `TickLabels` are already formatted with the desired `x`, that line of code will never be true.
Try changing the "Not Equal" Operator `<>` to `=` so that when an `x` *isn't* found in your TickLabel, it formats it to include it.

Comment: Hi Tate, thanks for your reply but that doesn't seem to work either I'm afraid

Comment: Is one of the other conditions in your `If-End If` block evaluating `True` before it reaches that portion?